# How can I understand "value" in bacis paxos

Tags: distributed-computing, distributed-system, consensus, paxos

I am reading Lamport's *Paxos Mode Simple*, and I get confused with the meaning "value" here.

For example, Lamport says:

> If a proposal with value v is chosen, then every higher-numbered proposal that is chosen has value v

I don't know what value v means here:

1. Does it mean different value of a certain variable, such as variable x's value can be 1 or 42?
2. Or is it something like one log entry in Raft, such as `x=1` or `y=42`?

I think the first interpretion is right, and basic Paxos can't determine multiple values, it just Propose-Accept-Chosen, and the whole basic Paxos instance finishes its mission.

However, I am not for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second interpretation is correct ("It's like one log entry in Raft").

You are also correct that Basic Paxos can't choose multiple values, it just chooses *one*, like a single log entry in Raft. To choose a series of values you need to chain multiple Basic Paxos instances together, like in Multi-Paxos or Raft.